# MariaDB 10 Data truncated in columns on INSERT, SELECT doesn't return offending rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a stored procedure I use which inserts into a table called `combined` the results from a select query. The procedure works, but consistently produces warnings: `(1265) Data Truncated for column 'Employee_StartTime' at row NNNN`

```
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                    |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'Employee_StartTime' at row 2107 |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'JobTitle_StartTime' at row 2107 |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'Employee_StartTime' at row 2108 |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'JobTitle_StartTime' at row 2108 |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'Employee_StartTime' at row 2109 |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'JobTitle_StartTime' at row 2109 |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'Employee_StartTime' at row 2110 |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'JobTitle_StartTime' at row 2110 |
... etc. for a total of 64 warnings (32 rows @ 2 warnings per row)
```

If I pull the select statement out of the procedure and execute it, I don't have any results at row NNNN.

```
... 
2106 rows in set (3.84 sec)

MariaDB [sr]> show warnings;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Schema is defined at [SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfd94f)

The Stored Proc follows:

```
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;

    DELETE
    FROM sr.combined;

    INSERT INTO sr.combined (
        Job_Title
        ,SizeOfPeerGroup
        ,VOC60_Rel30_Ten10
        ,Rel80_Ten20
        ,VOC60_TR20_Rel15_Ten5
        ,Column7
        ,ACW40_VOC40_Ten20
        ,AHT40_QA40_Ten20
        ,VOC_Pct
        ,`VOC Rank`
        ,Reliability_Pct
        ,`Reliability Rank`
        ,Av_ACW
        ,`ACW Rank`
        ,AHT
        ,`AHT Rank`
        ,QA_Pct
        ,`QA Rank`
        ,Lws_Ten_days
        ,`Tenure Rank`
        ,AFC_Pct
        ,`AFC Rank`
        ,wrID
        ,SalesID_num
        ,ACDID
        ,Employee
        ,DisplayName
        ,Employee_StartTime
        ,Campaign
        ,i360_JobTitle
        ,JobTitle_StartTime
        ,JobTitle_Tenure
        ,PeerGroupSize
        ,ReliabilityRatio
        ,Absent_Mins
        ,Non_FMLA_Sched_Mins
        ,Reliability_Rank
        ,QA_Ownership_Yes
        ,QA_Ownership_No
        ,QA_Opportunities
        ,QA_Ownership_InJobTitle
        ,QA_Rank
        ,Total_ACD_Calls
        ,Total_ACW_Time
        ,Avg_ACW
        ,ACW_Rank
        ,VOC_TakeRate
        ,VOC_TakeRate_Rank
        ,Total_AFC_Prod_Hrs
        ,Total_AFC_Sch_Hrs
        ,AFC_Perc
        ,AFC_Rank
        ,Total_HandleTime
        ,AHT_wAux10
        ,AHT_Rank
        ,AgentSat_Opportunities
        ,AgentSat_Points
        ,VOC_Perc
        ,VOC_Rank
        ,Lws_Tenure_days
        ,Tenure_Rank
        ,Lws_HireDate
        ,DEPTID
        ,LOCATION
        ,JOB_ENTRY_DT
        ,DEPT_ENTRY_DT
        ,POSITION_ENTRY_DT
        ,LWS_LCT_ENT_DT
        ,LWS_JOB_FAM_ENT_DT
        ,JOBCODE
        ,jobtitle
        ,DEPTNAME
        ,LWS_GRP_ID
        ,EMAILID
        )
    SELECT a.i360_JobTitle AS Job_Title
        ,a.`PeerGroupSize` AS SizeOfPeerGroup
        ,Cast(Rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY i360_JobTitle ORDER BY (
                        (`VOC Rank` * 0.6) + (Reliability_Rank * 0.3
                            ) + (Tenure_Rank * 0.1)
                        ) ASC
                ) AS INT) `VOC60_Rel30_Ten10`
        ,Cast(Rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY i360_JobTitle ORDER BY (
                        (Reliability_Rank * 0.8) + (Tenure_Rank * 0.2
                            )
                        ) ASC
                ) AS INT) `Rel80_Ten20`
        ,Cast(Rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY i360_JobTitle ORDER BY (
                        (VOC_TakeRate_Rank * 0.2) + (`VOC Rank` * 0.6
                            ) + (Reliability_Rank * 0.15) + (Tenure_Rank * 0.05
                            )
                        ) ASC
                ) AS INT) `VOC60_TR20_Rel15_Ten5`
        ,NULL `Column7`
        ,Cast(Rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY i360_JobTitle ORDER BY (
                        (ACW_Rank * 0.4) + (VOC_Rank * 0.4
                            ) + (Tenure_Rank * 0.2)
                        ) ASC
                ) AS INT) `ACW40_VOC40_Ten20`
        ,Rank() OVER (
            PARTITION BY i360_JobTitle ORDER BY (
                    (AHT_Rank * 0.4) + (QA_Rank * 0.4
                        ) + (Tenure_Rank * 0.2)
                    ) ASC
            ) `AHT40_QA40_Ten20`
        /*
        ,Cast(Rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY i360_JobTitle ORDER BY ((ADH_Rank * 0.4) + (QA_Rank * 0.4) + (Tenure_Rank * 0.2)) ASC
                ) AS NUMERIC) `ADH40_QA40_Ten20`
    */
        ,CASE 
            WHEN AgentSat_Opportunities > 0
                THEN Cast(100 * (AgentSat_Points * 1.0) / 
                        AgentSat_Opportunities AS DECIMAL(9, 6))
            ELSE NULL
            END AS VOC_Pct
        ,VOC_Rank AS `VOC Rank`
        ,ReliabilityRatio
        ,Reliability_Rank
        ,CASE 
            WHEN Total_ACD_Calls > 0
                THEN Cast((Total_ACW_Time * 1.0) / Total_ACD_Calls AS 
                        DECIMAL(22, 6))
            ELSE NULL
            END AS Av_ACW
        ,ACW_Rank AS `ACW Rank`
        ,CASE 
            WHEN Total_ACD_Calls > 0
                THEN (Total_HandleTime * 1.0) / total_acd_calls
            ELSE NULL
            END AS AHT
        ,AHT_Rank AS `AHT Rank`
        /*
        ,100 * ((ADH_Scheduled_hrs - ADH_OutOfAdh_hrs) / ADH_Scheduled_hrs) AS Adh_Pct
        ,ADH_Rank AS `ADH Rank`
    */
        ,CASE 
            WHEN `QA_Opportunities` > 0
                THEN 100 * ((QA_Ownership_Yes * 1.0) / `QA_Opportunities`
                        )
            ELSE NULL
            END AS QA_Pct
        ,QA_Rank AS `QA Rank`
        ,DateDiff(Date_Add(jobtitle_starttime, INTERVAL JobTitle_tenure DAY), Lws_HireDate) AS 
        Lws_Ten_days
        ,Tenure_Rank AS `Tenure Rank`
        ,CASE 
            WHEN Total_AFC_Sch_Hrs > 0
                THEN 100 * Cast((Total_AFC_Prod_Hrs * 1.0) / 
                        total_afc_sch_hrs AS DECIMAL(19, 6))
            ELSE NULL
            END AS AFC_Pct
        ,AFC_Rank AS `AFC Rank`
        ,a.*
    FROM (
        SELECT wfm.wrID
            ,wfm.SalesID_num
            ,wfm.ACDID
            ,wfm.Employee
            ,ppl.DisplayName
            ,wfm.Employee_StartTime
            ,wfm.Campaign
            ,wfm.JobTitle AS i360_JobTitle
            ,wfm.JobTitle_StartTime
            ,wfm.JobTitle_Tenure
            ,Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY wfm.JobTitle) AS PeerGroupSize
            ,wfm.ReliabilityRatio
            ,wfm.Absent_Mins
            ,wfm.Non_FMLA_Sched_Mins
            ,Rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY wfm.JobTitle ORDER BY wfm.ReliabilityRatio DESC
                ) AS Reliability_Rank
            ,wfm.`QA_Ownership_Yes`
            ,wfm.`QA_Ownership_No`
            ,wfm.`QA_Ownership_Yes` + wfm.`QA_Ownership_No` AS QA_Opportunities
            ,wfm.QA_Ownership_InJobTitle
            ,Rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY wfm.JobTitle ORDER BY wfm.QA_Ownership_InJobTitle DESC
                ) AS QA_Rank
            ,cms.Total_ACD_Calls
            ,cms.Total_ACW_Time
            ,CASE 
                WHEN cms.Total_ACD_Calls > 0
                    THEN Cast((cms.Total_ACW_Time * 1.0) / cms.
                            Total_ACD_Calls AS DECIMAL(22, 6))
                ELSE NULL
                END AS Avg_ACW
            ,Rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY wfm.JobTitle ORDER BY CASE 
                        WHEN cms.Total_ACD_Calls > 0
                            THEN (cms.Total_ACW_Time * 1.0) / 
                                cms.Total_ACD_Calls
                        ELSE NULL
                        END ASC
                ) AS ACW_Rank
            ,CASE 
                WHEN cms.Total_ACD_Calls > 0
                    THEN voc.AgentSat_Opportunities / cms.Total_ACD_Calls
                ELSE 0
                END VOC_TakeRate
            ,Rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY wfm.JobTitle ORDER BY CASE 
                        WHEN cms.Total_ACD_Calls > 0
                            THEN voc.AgentSat_Opportunities / cms.Total_ACD_Calls
                        ELSE 0
                        END DESC
                ) AS VOC_TakeRate_Rank
            /*
            ,adh.SumScheduled AS ADH_Scheduled_hrs
            ,adh.sumOutOfAdherence AS ADH_OutOfAdh_hrs
            ,100 * ((adh.SumScheduled - adh.sumoutofadherence) / adh.SumScheduled) AS Adh_Perc
            ,Cast(Rank() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY wfm.JobTitle ORDER BY CASE 
                            WHEN adh.sumscheduled > 0
                                THEN 100 * (adh.sumoutofadherence * 1.0) / adh.sumscheduled
                            ELSE NULL
                            END ASC
                    ) AS NUMERIC) AS ADH_Rank
    */
            ,Cast(cms2.Total_AFC_Prod_Hrs AS DECIMAL(20, 6)) AS Total_AFC_Prod_Hrs
            ,Cast(sch.Total_AFC_Sch_Hrs AS DECIMAL(20, 6)) AS Total_AFC_Sch_Hrs
            ,CASE 
                WHEN sch.Total_AFC_Sch_Hrs > 0
                    THEN 100 * Cast((cms2.Total_AFC_Prod_Hrs * 1.0) / 
                            sch.total_afc_sch_hrs AS DECIMAL(19, 6))
                ELSE NULL
                END AS AFC_Perc
            ,Rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY wfm.JobTitle ORDER BY CASE 
                        WHEN sch.Total_AFC_Sch_Hrs > 0
                            THEN 100 * (cms.Total_AFC_Prod_Hrs * 1.0
                                    ) / sch.total_afc_sch_hrs
                        ELSE NULL
                        END DESC
                ) AS AFC_Rank
            ,cms.Total_HandleTime
            ,CASE 
                WHEN cms.Total_ACD_Calls > 0
                    THEN (cms.Total_HandleTime * 1.0) / cms.
                        total_acd_calls
                ELSE NULL
                END AS AHT_wAux10
            ,Rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY wfm.JobTitle ORDER BY CASE 
                        WHEN cms.Total_ACD_Calls > 0
                            THEN (cms.Total_HandleTime * 1.0) / 
                                cms.total_acd_calls
                        ELSE NULL
                        END ASC
                ) AS AHT_Rank
            ,voc.AgentSat_Opportunities
            ,voc.AgentSat_Points
            ,CASE 
                WHEN voc.AgentSat_Opportunities > 0
                    THEN Cast(100 * (voc.AgentSat_Points * 1.0) / voc.
                            AgentSat_Opportunities AS DECIMAL(9, 6))
                ELSE NULL
                END AS VOC_Perc
            ,Rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY wfm.JobTitle ORDER BY CASE 
                        WHEN voc.AgentSat_Opportunities > 0
                            THEN 100 * (voc.AgentSat_Points * 1.0
                                    ) / voc.AgentSat_Opportunities
                        ELSE NULL
                        END DESC
                ) AS VOC_Rank
            ,DateDiff(Cast(Date_Add(wfm.jobtitle_starttime, INTERVAL wfm.JobTitle_tenure DAY) AS 
                    DATE), ppl.Hire_Dt) AS Lws_Tenure_days
            ,Rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY wfm.JobTitle ORDER BY DateDiff(Cast(Date_Add(wfm.jobtitle_starttime, 
                                INTERVAL wfm.JobTitle_tenure DAY) AS DATE), ppl.Hire_Dt) DESC
                ) AS Tenure_Rank
            ,ppl.HIRE_DT AS Lws_HireDate
            ,ppl.DEPTID
            ,ppl.LOCATION
            ,ppl.JOB_ENTRY_DT
            ,ppl.DEPT_ENTRY_DT
            ,ppl.POSITION_ENTRY_DT
            ,ppl.LWS_LCT_ENT_DT
            ,ppl.LWS_JOB_FAM_ENT_DT
            ,ppl.JOBCODE
            ,ppl.jobtitle
            ,ppl.DEPTNAME
            ,ppl.LWS_GRP_ID
            ,ppl.EMAILID
        FROM sr.t_wfm AS wfm
        INNER JOIN sr.t_ppl AS ppl
            ON wfm.SalesID_num = ppl.LWS_PNL_NBR
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT wfm.wrID
                ,Sum(cms.I_ACWTIME + cms.TI_AUXTIME10) AS Total_ACW_Time
                ,Sum(cms.ACDCALLS) AS Total_ACD_Calls
                ,Sum(cms.AFC_Hrs) AS Total_AFC_Prod_Hrs
                ,Sum(cms.I_ACDTIME + cms.I_ACWTIME + cms.TI_AUXTIME10 + cms.HOLDTIME) Total_HandleTime
            FROM sr.t_wfm wfm
            INNER JOIN sr.t_cms cms
                ON cms.LOGID = wfm.ACDID
                    AND cms.INTERVALSTART >= wfm.JobTitle_StartTime
            INNER JOIN sr.jt_split_map sm
                ON sm.JobTitle = wfm.JobTitle
                    AND sm.SPLIT = cms.SPLIT
            GROUP BY wfm.wrID
            ) AS cms
            ON wfm.wrID = cms.wrID
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT wfm.wrID
                ,Sum(cms.AFC_Hrs) AS Total_AFC_Prod_Hrs
            FROM sr.t_wfm wfm
            INNER JOIN sr.t_cms cms
                ON cms.logid = wfm.acdid
                    AND cms.intervalstart >= wfm.JobTitle_StartTime
            GROUP BY wfm.wrID
            ) AS cms2
            ON wfm.wrID = cms2.wrID
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT wfm.wrID
                ,Sum(sch.schDuration) AS Total_AFC_Sch_Hrs
            FROM sr.t_wfm wfm
            INNER JOIN sr.t_sch sch
                ON sch.SchWrID = wfm.wrID
                    AND sch.SchDay >= wfm.JobTitle_StartTime
            GROUP BY wfm.wrid
            ) AS sch
            ON wfm.wrID = sch.wrid
        /*
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT adh.wrID
                ,sum(adh.ADH_hrs) SumScheduled
                ,sum(adh.nonADH_hrs) sumOutOfAdherence
            FROM sr.t_adh adh
            INNER JOIN sr.t_wfm wfm
                ON adh.wrID = wfm.wrID
                    AND adh.GMT_Date >= wfm.JobTitle_StartTime
            GROUP BY adh.wrID
            ) AS adh
            ON wfm.wrID = adh.wrID
    */
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT wfm.wrID
                ,CASE 
                    WHEN Sum(voc.countOfSatisfaction) > 0
                        THEN Sum(voc.sumOfSatisfaction * 1.0) / Sum(voc.countOfSatisfaction)
                    ELSE NULL
                    END AS AgentSat_Percentage
                ,Sum(voc.sumOfSatisfaction) AS AgentSat_Points
                ,Sum(voc.countOfSatisfaction) AS AgentSat_Opportunities
            FROM sr.t_wfm wfm
            INNER JOIN sr.t_voc voc
                ON voc.ACDID = wfm.ACDID
                    AND voc.survey_date >= wfm.JobTitle_StartTime
            GROUP BY wfm.wrid
            ) AS voc
            ON wfm.wrid = voc.wrid
        ) a;

    COMMIT;
END
```

`Employee_StartTime` and `JobTitle_StarTime` are both `NULL`-able fields and neither is used in any index.

As an experiment, I modified the `SELECT` statement to only return a single column `a.wrID`, and I again receive no warnings, and the row count is still 2106 (as above.)

Is it safe to ignore these warnings? Do I have an error somewhere? What is causing these 'truncated fields' warnings for rows I can't see?

Comment: What is the datatype `Employee_starttime`, from both tables, target and source?

Comment: Source= `t_wfm.Employee_StartTime`: DATETIME(19)
Target= `combined.Employee_StartTime`: DATE(10)

Comment: Not sure where you got those 19 and 10 but if the source is `DATETIME` and the target `DATE`, then the time part has to be truncated. That's probably the reason of the warnings / errors.

Comment: Sorry to confuse, I copied those from the schema that I defined at SQL Fiddle. In the DB definition, it is just DATE and DATETIME. I'd accept that as an answer, if it explained how that implicit conversion works for the preceeding 2,106 rows, or why when I eliminate that type conversion (running just the SELECT) I still receive the same number of rows (and not rows that might've contained the truncated data)

Comment: @chrismeu - `DATETIME(19)` implies an old version of MySQL; please specify version(s).

Comment: @chrismeu - `SHOW WARNINGS` must be run _immediately_ after the statement causing the warnings.  Any other statement clears the list of warnings.

Comment: @RickJames - Thanks for your interest in my question. DATETIME(19) is an artifact from SQL Fiddle. The database is MariaDB 10.3.5, and the field is DATE/DATETIME. There are warnings from the insert query ("Note 1265" in the first preformatted block above) but no warnings from the SELECT itself.